# What does "蕊屁" mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, phrase

At https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyNNvgW1dSg&lc=z13jt1khfxr4zzw0k225sjfzzyn1hhebs04, someone wrote:

> 看完電影後整晚都在蕊屁OST

Another person wrote in reply:

> +1 瘋狂蕊批

What does "蕊屁" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`蕊屁`==`repeat`, you can think it's a kind of transliteration.